# How do i scrape specific news from news API in Python?

Tags: python, api, web-scraping

I have written the code like this for fetching the top headlines:

```
main_url = "https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=bbc-news&sortBy=top&apiKey=ENTER API KEY"
bbc_page = requests.get(main_url).json() 
article = bbc_page["articles"] 
results = [] 

for arr in article: 
    results.append(arr["title"]) 

for i in range(len(results)): 
    print(i + 1, results[i])
```

How do I extract the top headlines from a couple of news website pages searching for a list of keywords (e.g. about the Corona virus or other specific topics)?

Comment: `if "coronavirus" in arr["title"].lower():` ?

Answer (score 4):

[Documentation](https://newsapi.org/docs/client-libraries/python) shows you can use `q=` for `searching query`

Code from documentation but with `q='corona virus'`

```
from newsapi import NewsApiClient

# Init
newsapi = NewsApiClient(api_key='API_KEY') # fb3a5891a786455bb898f36e92b09f24

# /v2/top-headlines
top_headlines = newsapi.get_top_headlines(q='corona virus',
                                          sources='bbc-news,the-verge',
                                          category='business',
                                          language='en',
                                          country='us')

# /v2/everything
all_articles = newsapi.get_everything(q='corona virus',
                                      sources='bbc-news,the-verge',
                                      domains='bbc.co.uk,techcrunch.com',
                                      from_param='2017-12-01',
                                      to='2017-12-12',
                                      language='en',
                                      sort_by='relevancy',
                                      page=2)
```

More details in doc for [top-headlines](https://newsapi.org/docs/endpoints/top-headlines)

---

The same with `requests`.

You can put `API Key` in url but it is better to put it in header. Url can be saved in some logs.

I used `API Key` from [documentation](https://newsapi.org/docs/client-libraries/python) and it seems it is active but normally you should register on page and get own `API Key`.

```
import requests

API_KEY = 'fb3a5891a786455bb898f36e92b09f24'

params = {
    'q': 'corona virus',
    'source': 'bbc-news',
    'sortBy': 'top',
    'language': 'en',
    #'category': 'business',
    #'country': 'us',
    #'apiKey': API_KEY,
}

headers = {
    'X-Api-Key': API_KEY,  # KEY in header to hide it from url
}

url = 'https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines'

response = requests.get(url, params=params, headers=headers)
data = response.json()

articles = data["articles"] 
results = [arr["title"] for arr in articles] 

for i, arr in enumerate(results, 1): 
    print(i, arr)
```

My result:

```
1 Live updates: CPAC attendee tests positive for coronavirus; Italy considers locking down center of outbreak
2 Trump: Not concerned at all about coronavirus exposure - CNN Video
3 NHL starts closing dressing rooms to media to prevent spread of coronavirus
4 Two Australian Defence Force officers test positive for COVID-19
5 Princess says passenger brought coronavirus on ship; cruise companies to change boarding protocols
6 CPAC Attendee Tests Positive For Coronavirus, Didn't Have Contact With Trump
7 Hobart man who tested positive for coronavirus ignored direction to self-isolate and went to work at hotel
8 Health Minister says its 'not a day for criticism' as Coronavirus GP accuses health minister of 'grandstanding
9 U.S. conservative conference CPAC attendee tests positive for coronavirus
10 Italy poised to seal off north over coronavirus: Live updates
11 Elderly NSW man becomes third Australian to die with coronavirus
12 Coronavirus update: Two Australian Defence Force personnel infected
13 Live updates: CPAC attendee tests positive for coronavirus; Italy considers locking down center of outbreak
14 The divide between those who can buy in bulk, and those who can't
15 Live updates: CPAC attendee tests positive for coronavirus; Italy considers locking down center of outbreak
16 CPAC attendee tested positive for coronavirus
17 Hobart man who tested positive for coronavirus ignored direction to self-isolate and went to work at hotel
18 Coalition pulls multibillion-dollar coronavirus stimulus plan together
19 China January-February exports tumble, imports down as coronavirus batters trade and business
20 U.S. death toll from coronavirus hits 19, New York declares emergency
```